# PHP chinese segmentation

Tags: php

I'm looking for php chinese segmentation

because Chinese words don't have space, it affect fulltext search

ex.

```
$_GET['text']="中文分詞搜尋";
$text=$_GET['text'];(user's input)
$text; -chinese segment function-> $text="中文 分詞 搜尋";(result)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Search by each keyword? You mentioned *fulltext search*, do you mean you're going to search the keyword in database? Please provide more information.

Comment: what I need is break the string into words with space, because is different from English, Chinese don't have space in sentence, ex. I love PHP, in chinese it will be IlovePHP

Comment: yes I want to search keywords in database, ex. If use type I love PHP, In English, fulltext search will search those keywords (I, love, PHP)

Comment: You can use `mb_split`. See the question I marked as duplicate (Note: I know Japanese != Chinese, but they are in same category: multibyte character)

Comment: i'm not looking for explode, user's input don't have space, I need to go through a dictionary function to find out 中文,分詞,搜尋 those are 3 words and add space between

Comment: Guys - he isn't asking how to split on chars, he wants to split on Chinese words.

Comment: Stemming for Chinese may provide better results? https://code.google.com/p/sphinx-for-chinese/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$str = '蚂蚁学院，欢迎您的光临!';
function mbstringtoarray($str,$charset) {
  $strlen=mb_strlen($str);
  while($strlen){
    $array[]=mb_substr($str,0,1,$charset);
    $str=mb_substr($str,1,$strlen,$charset);
    $strlen=mb_strlen($str);
  }
  return $array;
}
$arr = mbstringtoarray($str,"gbk");
print_r($arr);
?>
```

The Output will be:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 蚂
  [1] => 蚁
  [2] => 学
  [3] => 院
  [4] => ，
  [5] => 欢
  [6] => 迎
  [7] => 您
  [8] => 的
  [9] => 光
  [10] => 临
  [11] => !
)
```

you cant divide it exactly word by word:
蚂蚁/学院/欢迎/您/的/光临

if you insist, you will need another table that to store these meaning full word, as php wont recognized it by default

Comment: You're exploding chars, not segmentation.